# Send browser audio stream over socket.io

Tags: audio, socket.io, stream

I'm using [socket.io-stream](https://github.com/nkzawa/socket.io-stream) to share file over socket from server t browser. I'd like to use the same to share audio stream from browser to server. Is it possible? I know that browser audio stream is different from node.js stream, so i need to convert it, how?

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure what you're expecting to do with the data, but [this answer may be of use to you.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50976084/how-do-i-stream-live-audio-from-the-browser-to-google-cloud-speech-via-socket-io/50976085#50976085)

Specifically, I'd suggest you use [getUserMedia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia) to get your audio, hook it up to a Script Processor, convert the data, and emit those data chunks to socket.io. Then on your server, you can capture those chunks and write them to your node.js stream. Code samples are at the link; they're fairly lengthy and I don't want to spam, so I won't reproduce them here.